# ruby is returning undefined method + for nil:nilClass

Tags: ruby

Running the following code:

```
# experiment
time = 5000
# when time reaches 10000, I'm off duty
def speedup_time(incre)
  time += incre
  yield(time)
end

puts "is the day over yet? #{speedup_time(2000){
  if incre >= 10000
    "yes: #{time}"
  else
    "no: #{time}"
  end
}}"
```

I ran into this error: `undefined method "+" for nil:nilClass`.

Comment: Ruby should `raise undefined local variable or method 'time'` but parser evulate `time` to `nil` and i can't understand why `time` equal `nil` in `def` scope?

Comment: @Зелёный, Because the parser sees this, `time =`, so the parser creates a variable called time and marks it as a local variable.  What that means is that the time variable exists, but that it hasn't been assigned a value yet.  Then the code executes, and the error is thrown.  The parser will do that even if it is impossible for the assignment statement to execute, e.g. `if false; time = 10; end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time` variable outside of scope(define method in `Ruby` have own scope and can't see any variables outside). Try this:

```
# when time reaches 10000, I'm off duty
def speedup_time(incre)
  time = 5000
  time += incre
  yield(time)
end
```

And you second expression wrong. I think should be something like:

```
speed_var = speedup_time(2000) do |time|
  if time >= 10000
    "yes: #{time}"
  else
    "no: #{time}"
  end
end
puts "is the day over yet? #{speed_var}"
```

Or short with ternary operator:

```
speed_var = speedup_time(2000) { |time| (time >= 10000) ? "yes: #{time}" : "no: #{time}" }
puts "is the day over yet? #{speed_var}"
```

or:

```
puts %Q|is the day over yet? #{speedup_time(2000){ |time| (time >= 10000) ? "yes: #{time}" : "no: #{time}"}}|
```

Comment: I was thinking of using the yield and adapt this to a promise.then style as I was accustomed to in javascript, is there a way to adapt this with yield.

Comment: @user2167582 look update answer if i understand right.

Comment: cool so `something end` is like a substitute for brackets: `{}`, do they define and divide all the blocks in ruby?

Comment: also, wouldn't speed up time of your version reset the time every time it runs? what if I want a global time? how can I access out-of-scope variables within function blocks or yield blocks.

Comment: @user2167582 `how can I access out-of-scope` this case can resolve by `instance variables` in class.

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking of using the yield and adapt this to a promise.then
>   style as I was accustomed to in javascript, is there a way to adapt
>   this with yield.

You are going to have to study blocks a little more because this won't work either:

```
def do_stuff(x)
  yield
end


do_stuff(10) { puts x }


--output:--
2.rb:6:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object (NameError)
    from 2.rb:2:in `do_stuff'
    from 2.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

It's pretty clear you are lost when it comes to scopes in ruby.  Get a beginning ruby book.  Read it.  Ruby is not javascript.

```
#----A def creates a new scope--+
def do_stuff               #    |
  x = 10                   #    |
end                        #    |
#-------------------------------+
#...which means nothing inside that box can see anything outside the box
#except for constants, which are visible everywhere

y = 20

p = Proc.new do  #Proc.new and lambda create anonymous functions in ruby
  puts y
  puts x
  puts z
end

def test(p) 
  z = 30
  p.call #execute proc, can also be written as p[]
end

test p
```

Play around with that example, commenting out various puts statements.

Comment: thanks, im grinding through some syntax and practice before getting totally lost in the books.

Comment: @Зелёный, Yeah, like loop variables are global variables. :(

Comment: @user2167582, Okay, here is some food for thought: a block can see all the variables in the surrounding scope at the time the block is CREATED.  A block can see NO variables in the surrounding scope at the time it is EXECUTED.  When you created your block, there was no variable called incre in the surrounding scope, so when your block is executed, it can NEVER see a variable called incre.  I'll post an example.